# A harmonic function cannot attain a strict local max in the domain

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I feel like I understand how the max principle works, but I don't understand the hint that was given on this problem. I am working on studying for an exam in a couple weeks. Any help would be much appreciated on how to use the hint.

The proof that I currently have is that by the mean value theorem, $$|f(a)|\leq |\frac1{2 \pi i}|\int_0^{2\pi} |f(a+Re^{i\theta})|d\theta$$

Suppose for the sake on contradiction that a is a strict local max in the domain D. Then $$|f(a)|> |\frac1{2 \pi i}|\int_0^{2\pi} |f(a+Re^{i\theta})|d\theta$$ which contradicts the above inequality. So we have that $|f(z)|$ cannot attain a strict local max in D.

Comment: Do you know that a real harmonic function is, locally, the real part of a holomorphic function?

Comment: The proof you have using the mean value theorem is correct and easy to understand. I don't know why you  need a more complicated proof.

Comment: @Somos thank you for the praise on my proof. Just always wanting to understand more math in different ways :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v(x, y)$ be a harmonic conjugate of $u(x, y)$ in $D$; then

$f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y) \tag 1$

is holomorphic in $D$, as is well-known.  Thus, so

$g(z) = e^{f(z)} = e^{u(x, y) + i v(x, y)} \tag 2$

is also holomorphic in $D$; this implies, by the maximum modulus principle, that $\vert g(z) \vert$ cannot attain a strict local maximum in $D$; but

$\vert g(z) \vert = \vert e^{f(z)} \vert = \vert e^{u(x, y) + i v(x, y)} \vert = \vert e^{u(x, y)} e^{i v(x, y)} \vert = \vert e^{u(x, y)} \vert \vert e^{i v(x, y)} \vert = e^{u(x, y)}, \tag 3$

since

$\vert e^{i v(x, y)} \vert = \vert \cos v(x, y) + i \sin v(x, y) \vert = 1 \tag 4$

and, since $e^{u(x, y)}$ is positive real,

$\vert e^{u(x, y)} \vert = e^{u(x, y)}; \tag 5$

since $\vert g(z) \vert$ cannot attain a strict local maximum in $D$, neither can the function $u(x, y)$, since it is, by (3), the log modulus of the holomorphic function $g(z)$:

$u(x, y) = \ln \vert g(z) \vert, \tag 6$

and $\ln$ is strictly monotonically increasing on the positive reals.

Comment: Great proof. Thank you

Comment: @MathIsHard:  You are most welcome.  Thanks for the good word, and for the 
"acceptance"!  Cheers!